# Module Level Configuration

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, module-params

I'm writing an add-in for Joomla and I have a question about modules. I'll be the first to admit I'm not a wizard on Joomla. I have read a bit and watched some tutorial videos.

Say I have a module that displays a mini-calendar. Can I have the mini-calendar display data from one set, while on a different page, the same mini-calendar module displays data from another set?

In WordPress, when you drag a widget into an area, you can specify the settings for the widget, in that specific area. You can even drag the same widget into a specific area multiple times and specify different operating parameters for each widget instance. Is there something analogous in Joomla?

If modules aren't the way to go, could anyone please give me a pointer on the direction I should go?

Comment: If you want it to act differently on different pages, you can add your own parameters/options in the XML file, assign the module to menu item 1, duplicate it and assign the duplicated module with different parameters selected, to menu item 2

Comment: This is for a commercial product. I don't think most end-users are going to have that level of skill.

Comment: George, is the website the commercial product or the module?  The bigger question is what's the differentiating business logic which determines what the calendar should display on the various pages?

Comment: The module is GPL, but it's basically an interface to a commercial product. The commercial product is a calendar. Here's a sample. We have a simple list of events widget. It can extract events from the calendar based on the calendar, or the type of event. There might be multiple calendars. For a church, an example would be Women's Ministries, and the whole church. Each ministry area could have their own page with their own simple list. Another example would be today's events, or this week's events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say I have a module that displays a mini-calendar. Can I have the mini-calendar display data from one set, while on a different page, the same mini-calendar module displays data from another set?

Yes, you would simply need to include a field for the ICS calendar feed in your module. Each instance of the module could have a different value there.

> In WordPress, when you drag a widget into an area, you can specify the settings for the widget, in that specific area. You can even drag the same widget into a specific area multiple times and specify different operating parameters for each widget instance. Is there something analogous in Joomla?

Yes, but not using "drag-n-drop." You would simply create a new module of the same "Type" and assign it to the same module "Position" for each instance of the module you want. You can even choose the "Ordering" of the modules in the same position.

> If modules aren't the way to go, could anyone please give me a pointer on the direction I should go?

Yes, it sound like modules are absolutely the way to go!

---

Here are a few recommended reads:

- [Modules](https://docs.joomla.org/Module) Documentation
- [Joomla modules vs WordPress widgets](https://www.gavick.com/blog/joomla-modules-wordpress-widgets)
- [Comparing Joomla and WordPress: Nomenclature](https://www.gavick.com/blog/comparing-joomla-wordpress-nomenclature)

Answer (score 0):

Hi George and Welcome to JSE!

A module sounds like a reasonable solution for your scenario.

Parameters can be included in the module to make it easy for users to choose what information to display in each instance of the module that is created.

Modules can then be individually assigned to pages as required such as "On all pages", "Only on the pages selected" or "On all pages except those selected" etc as per the example below.

[image: Menu Assignment]